# How to avoid .git files when comparing two folders

Tags: linux, git, command-line, terminal, diff

I have git installed on my Mac. I am trying to make a diff between files in two different folders.

```
diff -rq PATH_Folder1/ PATH_Folder2/ > Desktop/DIFF.txt
```

The results include .git files.

```
Example:
Files PATH1/abi/cpp/.git/index and PATH2/abi/cpp/.git/index differ.
```

How can I avoid comparing .git files. I don't require comparing git indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the -x option to exclude file patterns. So for this case it would be:

```
diff -rq -x .git PATH_Folder1/ PATH_Folder2/ > Desktop/DIFF.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `git diff` rather than simple diff, which should know to avoid `.git` files and the like. [Here is the reference for the `git diff` command.](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)

Even better would be [using a graphical diff tool](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) with

```
$ git difftool -t meld
```

or

```
$ git difftool -t kdiff3
```

Several guides and howtos exist out there. [This is a good example.](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-gui/)